# Override bootstrap css in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

All the css is ok but the only problem is that I can't change the default bootstrap css.

**index.html.erb**:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 no-padding"> Something </div>
```

**_cards.scss**:

```
.no-padding{
  padding: 0px !important;
}
```

Is there any configuration that is causing it?

The only way that works in this app is to write:

```
<div class="col-sm-6" style="padding: 0px;"> Something </div>
```

*Obs.: I'm using Rails 5.0.1 and I created a new sample of rails app to test and worked like how I intended to do. So I guess that it should be some wrong configuration.*

*Obs2.: all other components from '_card.scss' are also loading normally.*

Comment: Are you loading your css files after bootstrap styles?

Comment: Yes, I noticed and when I changed the order on `application.scss` it worked on production but in localhost it didn't. So maybe I have another problem here...Thank you for your answer anyway.

Comment: How are you including the files in your application.scss?

Comment: Hi @Iceman, today I just opened up on localhost and curiously it was working fine like it was already going on production environment. Thank you all for the hints!

Comment: Ok, good to hear.

Comment: If this solved, would you add a self-answer below? We prefer titles not to be updated with "solved" messages, since we have a fully-fledged acceptance system instead.

Comment: @halfer you are 100% right!

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue we have to attempt to call on `application.scss` the bootstrap first (I mean, above on the list) and then we should call our private css folders after.

Thank you again for the amazing support guys.